# Scalability issues with server based authentication

Tags: authentication, server, scalability

I was reading up on problems with server based authentication. I need help with elaboration on the following point.

> Scalability: Since sessions are stored in memory, this provides problems with scalability. As our cloud providers start replicating servers to handle application load, having vital information in session memory will limit our ability to scale.

I don't seem to understand why "... having vital information in session memory will limit our ability to scale", will limit the ability to scale. Is it just because the information is being replicated.. so it's to do with redundancy? I don't think so. Anyway, would anyone be kind enough to explain this further? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server-based authentication makes use of sessions, which in turn make use of a local session id. In the cloud, when the servers are replicated to handle application load, it becomes difficult for one server to know which sessions are active on other servers. Now to overcome this problem, extra steps must be performed... for instance to persist the session id on to the database. However, as the servers are increasingly replicated, it becomes more and more difficult to handle all this. Therefore, server-based or session-based authentication can be problematic for scalability.

Answer (score 2):

What's being referred to is the difference between stateless and stateful server-side ops.  Stateful servers keep part of their resources (main memory, mostly) occupied for retaining state pertaining to some client, even when the server is actually doing nothing at all for the client and just waiting for the client to come back.  Such systems' performance profile is "linear" only up to the point where all available memory has been filled with state, and beyond that point the server seems to essentially stall.  Stateless servers only keep resources occupied when they're actually doing something, and once finished doing stuff, those resources are immediately freed and available for other clients.  Such servers are essentially not capped by memory limits and therefore "scale easier".

Also, the explanation given seems to refer to scenario's where a set of distinct machines present themselves to the outside world as being one, when actually they are not (this is often called a "cluster" of machines/servers).  In such scenario's, if a client has connected to the "big single virtual machine", then actually he is connected to just one of the "actual machines" in the cluster.  If state is kept there, subsequent visits by that same client must then be routed to the same physical machine, or that piece of state must be trafficked around to whatever machine the next visit happens to be to.  The former implies the implementation of management functions that take their own set of resources, plus limitations on the freedom the cluster has to distribute the load (the opposite of why you want to do clustering), the latter implies additional network traffic that will cap scalability in essentially the same way as available memory does.

Comment: Wow! Incredible detail... in fact, almost a bit too much. Thank you nonetheless.